# Special Singleton (like None)

Tags: python

How would I go about making a special singleton, like `None`? (I'm new to python.)

I want to be able to do this sort of thing:

```
def create_mutations(d):
    return [
        Mutation(c, v)
        if v is not CellAction.Delete else
        Mutation(c, isDelete=True)
        for (c, v) in d
        ]
```

Used like this:

```
create_mutations({'a': 5, 'b': None, 'c': CellAction.Delete})
```

This would create a list containing three mutations, meaning "set `a` to `5`, set `b` to `None`, and delete `c`."

The point is that in the definition of `create_mutations` I cannot use `... if v is not None else ...` because then there is no distinction between "set `b` to `None`" and "delete `b`."

I can clarify if the question isn't clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just instantiate an `object` somewhere in your module or class like this:

```
Delete = object()
```

This is enough for most cases.

Comment: This works just fine - I didn't realize you could just dump a line like that at the top level in a file defining classes.

Answer (score 3):

Simply make some object and give it a name. An empty class will do:

```
class Delete:
    pass
```

Or, as Michael notes, an `object` instance.

Whatever object you use should be mutable if you plan to test for it using `is`; Python has a habit of sharing instances of immutable objects. (For example, all empty tuples are the same object.)

Comment: I've seen a few projects that merge both answers, and have something like `DELETE = Delete()`

Comment: @JonathanVanasco What does that accomplish?

Comment: With `DELETE = object()`, you must always check `if foo is DELETE`.  With `DELETE = Delete()`, you can check using `if isinstance(DELETE, Delete)`.  Depending on what you're working with, it may be better to use `isinstance` with a class than `is` with an object.  For example, if you're persisting data (pickle, shelf, marshall, etc), `DELETE = object()` will be different on subsequent runs of your program and will not match your persisted data, however testing against a custom `Delete` class will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simple answer is you can't (well, you *could*, but that's not what you want to do).

You should probably just use a class here, such as `DeleteCell = object()` (or, you could have a `CellAction` class or module with various actions (other classes) inside of it).